# iPad as Mac Display: How to return to Mac desktop from iPad home screen?

Tags: macos, ipad, display, sidecar

I'm using my iPad as a secondary display. The menu bar icon on my Mac is blue (active), my Mac desktop is on the iPad.

I press the iPad's home button. I'm now on the iPad's home screen. The Mac is still connected, the menu bar icon is still blue.

How can I quickly return to viewing my Mac desktop on the iPad?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are on the latest macOS (11.2.1) and iPadOS (14.4) version and using Sidecar? I don't get the blue menu button nor the blue menu bar, however, under last used apps on my iPad I can simply open the Sidecar app (https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/macos/Catalina/ipados13-sidecar-icon.png) and it gets me back to the Mac display.

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking everywhere...settings, control center, gestures...didn't think to look under recently used apps. Thanks so much!